# Photoshop align pixels perfectly to mm

Tags: alignment, photoshop, pixel, pixel-perfect

Hi there from the image below you will see some guides that are set 1mm apart but the pixel lines I have drawn are not aligned nor am I able to get them aligned to the mm. moving the lines with the anchor tool causes them to loses the solidness and bleed into other pixels. does anyone know away to get the pixels to align to the mm?

may just be something Im missing

example image
http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/51/ruleo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going to your Snap To settings under the View menu and seeing what is turned on or off in there.

You could definitely turn snapping off and manually match the elements up to the lines.

Comment: Snapping is turned off but still it just skips over the where the guides are... I think this is a screen DPI issue.... I changed the screen dpi to 300 and I was able to align this up (Im working on print 300DPI)